# Text To Speech (Multi Lang) Using gTTS API In Python

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech, google-translation-api

I am actually trying to make a text to speech code where the text which is written in any language will be spoken out loud. The language in which it will speak should be selected by the user in a dropdown. I have written the code which I will be showing below.

```
import gtts
import os
import playsound
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator, LANGUAGES
import tkinter as tk 

root=Tk()
root.title("TEXT TO SPEECH")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg="#305065")

#Top Text
Label(root,text="TEXT TO SPEECH",font="Helvetica 20 bold",fg="white",bg='#305065').pack(pady=10)

a=tk.StringVar()
auto_select=ttk.Combobox(frame1,width=27,textvariable=a,state='readonly',font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
auto_select['values'] = (

    'Afrikaans',
    'Albanian',
    'Amharic',
    'Arabic',
    'Armenian',
    'Azerbaijani',
    'Basque',
    'Belarusian',
    'Bengali',
    'Bosnian',
    'Bulgarian',
    'Batalan',
    'Cebuano',
    'Chichewa',
    'Chinese (simplified)',
    'Chinese (traditional)',
    'Corsican',
    'Croatian',
    'Czech',
    'Danish',
    'Dutch',
    'English',
    'Esperanto',
    'Estonian',
    'Filipino',
    'Finnish',
    'French',
    'Frisian',
    'Galician',
    'Georgian',
    'German',
    'Greek',
    'Gujarati',
    'Gaitian creole',
    'Hausa',
    'Hawaiian',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hindi',
    'Hmong',
    'Hungarian',
    'Icelandic',
    'Igbo',
    'Indonesian',
    'Irish',
    'Italian',
    'Japanese',
    'Javanese',
    'Kannada',
    'Kazakh',
    'Khmer',
    'Korean',
    'Kurdish (kurmanji)',
    'Kyrgyz',
    'Lao',
    'Latin',
    'Latvian',
    'Lithuanian',
    'Luxembourgish',
    'Macedonian',
    'Malagasy',
    'Malay',
    'Malayalam',
    'Maltese',
    'Maori',
    'Marathi',
    'Mongolian',
    'Myanmar (burmese)',
    'Nepali',
    'Norwegian',
    'Odia',
    'Pashto',
    'Persian',
    'Polish',
    'Portuguese',
    'Punjabi',
    'Romanian',
    'Russian',
    'Samoan',
    'Scots gaelic',
    'Serbian',
    'Sesotho',
    'Shona',
    'Sindhi',
    'Sinhala',
    'Slovak',
    'Slovenian',
    'Somali',
    'Spanish',
    'Sundanese',
    'Swahili',
    'Swedish',
    'Tajik',
    'Tamil',
    'Telugu',
    'Thai',
    'Turkish',
    'Ukrainian',
    'Urdu',
    'Uyghur',
    'Uzbek',
    'Vietnamese',
    'Welsh',
    'Xhosa',
    'Yiddish',
    'Yoruba',
    'Zulu',
    )

auto_select.place(x=150,y=60)

#Textboxes & Buttons
sor_txt=Text(frame1,width=40,height=11,borderwidth=5,relief=RIDGE,font=('verdana',15))
sor_txt.place(x=30,y=110)
dest_txt=Text(frame1,width=40,height=11,borderwidth=5,relief=RIDGE,font=('verdana',15))
dest_txt.place(x=710,y=110)

button_change=Button(frame1,text="TRANSLATE",relief=RAISED,borderwidth=2,font=('verdana',10,'bold'),bg='#248aa2',cursor="hand2",command=translate)
button_change.place(x=590,y=430,width=100,height=40)
button_clear=Button(frame1,text="CLEAR",relief=RAISED,borderwidth=2,font=('verdana',10,'bold'),bg='#248aa2',cursor="hand2",command=clear)
button_clear.place(x=590,y=480,width=100,height=40)

#Translator_Code

def translate():
    lang_1=sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    cl=choose_lang.get()

    if lang_1 == '':
        messagebox.showerror("TEXT TO SPEECH","Enter the text to translate!")
    else:
        dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
        translator=Translator()
        output=translator.translate(lang_1,dest=cl)
        dest_txt.insert('end',output.text)

    dest_audio = gtts.gTTS(output.text, lang=cl)
    playsound.playsound(dest_audio)

def clear():
    sor_txt.delete(1.0,'end')
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,'end')

root.mainloop()
```

After executing this code I am getting a error where it is saying language not found. So may someone tell me who can I solve this?

Screenshot of my Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mk5A.png

Answer (score 0):

Check out the supported languages here: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

for example "Amharic" isn't a supported language so simply fix the list of languages by removing unsupported languages